# Como sobrescrever o type "string" do localstorage para um outro type com typescript?

Tags: react, typescript, tipagem, react-hooks, localstorage

tenho um componente em React de tema (mas esse problema é de typescript, não necessáriamente precisa de React), esse componente precisa usar o **localstorage** para definir o tema inicial gravado em um state caso o usuário já tenha definido isso anteriormente. O problema é que quero que meu state só aceite os valores: **null**, **"light"** e **"dark"** (presente dentro de um type personalizado chamado **"theme"**), mas o *localstorage só retorna null e "string"*.

```ts
// o storage apenas terá o valor "dark" ou "light" se estiver definido, mas seu type padrão sempre é "string"
const storage = window.localStorage.getItem('MY_PAGE_THEME')
type themes = ("light" | "dark")

export const MyThemeProvider() {
  let pageDefaultTheme = storage || "light"
  
  // a Linha 9 terá o seguinte erro: "O argumento do tipo 'string' não é atribuível ao parâmetro do tipo 'themes | (() => themes)'.ts(2345)"
  const [pageTheme, setPageTheme] = useState<themes>(pageDefaultTheme)
  
  // code...
}
```

Gostaria de corrigir isso para que meu state só aceite o meu type personalizado **"themes"**

Comment: Acho que dá para generalizar a sua pergunta. Não tem muito a ver com React, o foco é totalmente TypeScript; então seria legal dar uma editada para fazer isso. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lembre-se que o TypeScript não consegue garantir, só a partir de uma *definição* de tipos, que um valor de fato terá aquele tipo.

Voltemo-nos ao seu tipo `Themes`:

```
type Themes = 'light' | 'dark';
```

Veja que ele só aceita strings que sejam exatamente `light` ou `dark`. No entanto, o tipo `string` (retornado pelo método `localStorage.getItem`) é uma string.

E, obviamente, o tipo string, representando a infinita possibilidade de strings, é bem mais amplo que o seu tipo `Themes`, que codifica somente duas dessas possibilidades.

Portanto, o TypeScript rejeita o seu código – e rejeita corretamente. Só com o que ele tem, não há como garantir que a variável `storage` (do tipo `string`, que veio do método `getItem`) de fato é atribuível ao tipo `light` ou `dark`. Nada impediria que fosse uma string `modified-haha`.

Esse é o caso de se utilizar um recurso do TypeScript chamado [***type guard***](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). Você basicamente utiliza de mecanismos em *runtime* (estaticamente compreendidos pelo TypeScript) que podem afirmar, com certeza, que o valor que você está utilizando trata-se do tipo desejado.

Um exemplo simples:

```
type Theme = 'dark' | 'light';

const userTheme = localStorage.getItem('MY_PAGE_THEME');

if (userTheme === 'dark' || userTheme === 'light') {
    // Aqui o TypeScript é capaz de determinar que o tipo de `rawTheme` é `Theme`:
  const ok: Theme = userTheme; // Não dá erros.
}
```

Uma outra opção é negar a condição e utilizar um mecanismo disruptivo (que modifica o fluxo de código) dentro do bloco condicional, como um lançamento de exceção ou `return` da função:

```
type Theme = 'dark' | 'light';

function normalizeTheme(raw: string | null): Theme {
    if (!(userProvidedTheme === 'dark' || userProvidedTheme === 'light')) {
        return 'dark'; // Valor padrão, obviamente do tipo `Theme`.
    }
    return userProvidedTheme; // Ok. Aqui o TypeScript tem certeza que trata-se do tipo `Theme`.
}

const userTheme = localStorage.getItem('MY_PAGE_THEME');
const theme = normalizeTheme(userTheme);
```

É importantíssimo entender a diferença entre as verificações estáticas feitas pelo TypeScript e a diferença entre código *runtime*. Eventualmente, conduto, o TypeScript *precisa* que você alie verificações em *runtime* (codificadas via *guardas*) para que ele possa garantir que um valor mais genérico é, realmente, de um tipo mais exclusivo.

Claro que a guarda, eventualmente, pode conter erros de lógica. Mas aí não é culpa do TypeScript, que não tem outra alternativa senão delegar esse tipo de verificação manual ao programador. Em resumo, veja guardas como um recurso extremamente poderoso, mas que deve ser utilizado com cuidado.